# Spring JPA can't persist collection item with related existing entity - detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I got an issue when trying to persist an item of a collection and one of its properties is an already persistent entity in a database.

Trying to clarify by this simplified example:

- Class A has a List of class B (One to Many, mappedBy, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE)
- Class B is related back to A (Many to One, JoinColumn)
- Class B inherits from BParent (Single Table)
- BParent is related to class C (Many to One, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST)

When i run ARepository.save(entity) passing a complete object to it (with a List of B including one B entity with a new C associated) it persists all entities normally.

When i run ARepository.save(entity) passing an object related with existing (with List of B including a B entity realted with a EXISTING C associated, i.e. id only) it triggers the dettached entity passed to persist error.

```
 org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: C
```

What im trying to do is to save a new related object (when it has no id) or associate to an existing object (when it has an id).

My respositories are all Spring Data JpaRepository interfaces. My code goes like this (getters and setters ommited):

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bEntity", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class B extends BParent {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CVLE_CVL_UUID")
    private A bEntity;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CVLE_TIPO")
@Table( name = "TAB_CONTA_VINCULADA_LANC_EMPREGADO")
public abstract class BParent {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "CVLE_EMP_UUID")
    private C cEntity;  
}

@Entity
@Table( name = "TAB_EMPREGADO")
public class C {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMP_UUID")
    private UUID id;

}
```

I hope i could explain it right (english is not my first language). I would appreciate if someone could give me a hand on this, thank you.

Comment: This happens when you are trying to persist an entity which is in detached state i.e: not currently managed by entityManager. https://javabeat.net/hibernate-detached-entity/ Here are some common problems which can cause this. Also share the code where you are saving the entities. It will help to debug.

Comment: ***"When i run ARepository.save(entity) passing an object related with existing..."***  You mentioned that you are passing object related with existing B and C? I think these existing B and C might be detached. You can either reattach these or demarcate the Transaction properly so that these B and C are never detached.

Comment: Try to do the logic only in function which have a `@Transaction` annotation. Inside these methods, the objects shouldn't be detached from the transaction. Or do you explizitly want to detach them?